# MsTest is not available from Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, mstest

I have Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate but it looks like mstest is not available: there are no mstest templates at "Add new item" and I see no reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools at "Add reference" dialog. What should I do to enable mstest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a project template, not an item template.  File + Add + Project, pick from the Test Projects node.

Comment: I have no Test Projects node. Looks like MsTest is not installed at all

Comment: Hm... I added reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework manually and it works now. But it looks like something is wrong with my Visual Studio installation